# .Net core CLI DbContext scaffold changed table name to sigular

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

For an existing database and with existing code, after upgraded from .Net core 3.x to .Net 5, all mapped classes from below command become singular, e.g. books -> book:

C:\myproject>dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold connectionstr  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -f -o ..\Data\Models\ApplicationData

And here is the version info:

```
C:\myproject>dotnet --version
5.0.303

C:\myproject>dotnet ef --version
Entity Framework Core .NET Command Line Tools
2.0.3-rtm-10026
```

I also used --use-database-names, seems no effect. Plus, I'm happy with EF generated column names :). But how can I keep the s/ies at the end of the class's name?

**Update:**
I updated the CLI tool by issuing this command:

> dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0

The update was successful. And it's still the same version 2.0.3-rtm-10026. The command list is same too.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the best way but there is a release on its way. I downgraded three EF packages (.design,sqlserver and tools) from 5.0.15 to 3.1.24, and that solved the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the --no-pluralize option.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes